# Intersection of two lists with repetitions

Tags: c#, list, intersection

I'm trying to create a function that will give me the intersection of two lists, taking into account that there can be repeated items and I need them in the output.

```
Console.Write((new[] {1, 2, 2, 3}).Intersect(new[] {1, 2, 2}));
```

only outputs {1, 2} and what I need the output to be is {1, 2, 2}.

Here is the method I have created:

```
private static IEnumerable<int> IntersectWithRepetitons(List<int> a, List<int> b)
{
    if (!a.Any() || !b.Any()) return Enumerable.Empty<int>();
    if (a.Count() > b.Count()) return IntersectWithRepetitons(b, a);

    var idx = b.IndexOf(a.First());
    if (idx < 0) return IntersectWithRepetitons(b, a.Skip(1).ToList());

    var tmp1 = new List<int> { a.First() };
    var tmp2 = new List<int>(b);
    tmp2.RemoveAt(idx);
    return tmp1.Concat(IntersectWithRepetitons(tmp2, a.Skip(1).ToList()));
}
```

I'm sure this can be highly optimized but, my main concern (efficiency wise) is that in order to keep the input lists intact, I have to duplicate the 'b' list when I remove a found item from it:

```
var tmp2 = new List<int>(b);
tmp2.RemoveAt(idx);
```

and that will happen for every recursive call.
Any thoughts or ideas will be very appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You're iterating each input sequence *many* times, and regularly copying n-1 items to new lists, both of which are really very problematic.

Comment: Why should the output only have one `1` even though there are two in the second set, and three between both set's combined?

Comment: sorry Servy I made a mistake in my example, it is corrected now

Comment: Are you interested in preserving order in any way? If not, I would make a dictionary that maps values to the number of occurrences in each list, then do a single linear scan through each list to populate this data. Finally, scan through the dictionary to find keys for which there is at least one entry in both lists, and output them into the result however many times it occurs. Fairly straightforward.

Comment: No need to preserve the order, could you elaborate your idea a little bit Asad?

Comment: What would be the output if, say, first list was `{1, 2, 2, 3}` and second list `{1, 2}`?

Comment: the output would be {1, 2} in that case Josh

Comment: converting into a hashset will remove the duplicates emodendroket

Comment: You're right; I was misled by your sample output in the comments.

Comment: And if first list was `{1, 2, 3}` and second list `{1, 2, 2}`? (Sorry, I'm just trying to fully understand the logic you're trying to implement)

Comment: Same thing Josh, {1, 2}

Comment: @JoshPart Think of it that you should yield an item for each time it exists in both sets.  Or worded another way, yield each item N times, where N is the minimum number of times it appears in either set.  So if `2` appears in both sets once, yield it once, if it appears in both sets twice, yield it twice.  if it's in one set twice, and another once, then it's in both sets a *minimum* of one time.

Comment: @Servy yeah, actually I was beggining to think of it that way; and trying to figure out the quickest way to return each element the minimun times it appears on both sets. Somehow sounds actually like a code-golf challenge

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Map one of the sequences to a dictionary of items to the count of times they appear, then for each item in the other sequence, if it's in the collection, and the value of the lookup is greater than zero, yield it and decriment:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> IntersectWithRepetitons<T>(this IEnumerable<T> first,
    IEnumerable<T> second)
{
    var lookup = second.GroupBy(x => x)
        .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.Count());
    foreach (var item in first)
        if (lookup.ContainsKey(item) && lookup[item] > 0)
        {
            yield return item;
            lookup[item]--;
        }
}
```

This ensures that items are yields for each time they are duplicated in both sets.

You could use `TryGetValue` to remove a few dictionary lookups, but it sacrifices a lot of the method's elegance, so I just didn't have it in me to do that.  If you care about performance, it's not a bad thing to change.

Comment: I like this idea... will the result be the same for IntersectWithRepetitons(lista, listb) and IntersectWithRepetitons(listb, lista)?

Comment: Thanks Servy! I'll definitely use this method :)